# Signup and Licensing for Redbus API?

Tags: web-services

How to Signup and get LoginID and password to access RedBus Api?

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like, Redbus has not yet opened up the web service to the public. Aparently the web service exposed is for only Bus operators with their own credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The API is open only to registered merchant or integrator. I got one and they will give based on your operation country. As in my case, I registered only for Malaysia, paid about 300 usd for the registration and given the api key. Although I would say their technical support is not the best as I've implemented in PHP and they didn't really have the expertise to support integration using PHP. The most problematic part is the seat selection process. The rest was quite straightforward.

I suggest that you take a look at their website and see what if there is any merchant registration link. As in my case, we came to their regional office and registered there.